# Run python scripts multiple times through Ansible playbook with command line arguments

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, command-line-arguments

I am trying to run a Python script multiple times through my `Ansible` playbook using with_items to take different command line arguments with each iteration, but even though, it iterates through the loop to take different names for the generated files, but the contents of the files remain the same: i.e. it only shows the content of the command output of `"show version" NX-OS`.

How can I iterate over the `{{ output }}` coming from the previous task?

Context: NX-OS CLI commands on Cisco Nexus 3k switches

**tasks/main.yml**:

```
---
- name: Run basic CLI commands on nexus 3k switch
  nxos_command: 
      provider: "{{ nxos_provider }}"
      commands: "{{ item.cmd1 }}"
  with_items: "{{ commands }}"
  register: output
- debug: var=output

- name: Run python script and store command output
  command: python /users/aastha/play/script.py  {{ item.name1 }}  {{ output }}
  with_items: "{{ commands }}"
```

**vars/main.yml**:

```
---
nxos_provider:
   host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
   username: "{{ un }}"
   password: "{{ pwd }}"
   transport: nxapi
   timeout: 500

commands:
   - cmd1: show version
     name1: pre-show-version

   - cmd1: show interface brief
     name1: pre-interface
```

**script.py**:

```
import json
import sys

arg = sys.argv[2:]
print(arg)
aas='\n'.join(map(str, arg))
print aas
with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.write(aas)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping over the wrong thing.  When you have...

```
- name: Run python script and store command output
  command: python /users/aastha/play/script.py  {{ item.name1 }}  {{ output }}
  with_items: "{{ commands }}"
```

...you're looking over the `commands` variable.  That means that `output` is always referring to the same thing.  Take a look at the documentation on [using `register` in a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop):

> After using register with a loop, the data structure placed in the variable will contain a results attribute that is a list of all responses from the module.

You actually want to loop over `output.results`, for example:

```
- name: Run python script and store command output
  command: python /users/aastha/play/script.py  {{ item.item.name1 }}  {{ item.stdout }}
  with_items: "{{ output.results }}"
```

In the above, `item.item` refers to the loop value in your *first*
loop (which loop over the `commands` variable).  I'm making some
assumptions here; I don't actually know what the structure of each
item in `output.results` looks like because you didn't post the output
of your `debug` task.  I'm pretending that the attribute `item.stdout`
has the value in which you are interested, but it's probably named
something else.